# Google Map travel mode in api

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In new google map there are several travel mode like driving, bicycling, walking and transit but they also added fly mode also. I can choose fly mode in new google map but i cant get fly travel mode in google maps v3 api. I want to to show fly distance between two cities on my site like google map shows on google map.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?sensor=false&origin=Lahore&destination=Multan&mode=driving

```
$base_url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?sensor=false';
$xml = simplexml_load_file("$base_url&origin=Lahore&destination=Multan");
echo $distance = (string)$xml->route->leg->distance->text;
echo $duration = (string)$xml->route->leg->duration->text
```

driving, walking and other modes are working but fly is not working.

Comment: Whats your problem tell me clearly

Comment: i want to calculate flight distance between two cities and also show that on map

Answer (score 0):

Waking and Driving mode only applicable in Google maps api. Fly mode is not available.

Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference?csw=1#GTravelModes)

Comment: link is for v2 tell me about new v3 api

Comment: this is the fly direction on google map https://www.google.com/maps/preview?authuser=0#!data=!4m23!3m22!1m5!1sLahore%2C+Pakistan!2s0x39190483e58107d9%3A0xc23abe6ccc7e2462!3m2!3d31.54505!4d74.340683!1m5!1sLondon%2C+UK!2s0x47d8a00baf21de75%3A0x52963a5addd52a99!3m2!3d51.5112139!4d-0.1198244!2e4!3m8!1m3!1d21418998!2d37.11135!3d42.071099!3m2!1i1344!2i678!4f13.1&fid=0   you can view this link you are sign in with google map